# Use [msys] bash to remove all files whose name matches a pattern, regardless of file-name letter-case

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell

I need a way to clean up a directory, which is populated with C/C++ built-files (.o, .a, .EXE, .OBJ, .LIB, etc.) produced by (1) some tools which always create files having UPPER-CASE names, and (2) other tools which always create lower-case file names.  (I have no control over the tools.)

I need to do this from a MinGW 'msys' bash.exe shell script (or bash command prompt).  I understand piping (|), but haven't come up with the right combination of exec's yet.  I have successfully filtered the file names, using commands like this example:

```
ls | grep '.\.[eE][xX][eE]'
```

to list all files having any case-combination of letters in the file-extension--this example gets all the executable (e.g. ".EXE") files.

(I'll be doing similar for .o, .a, .OBJ, .LIB, .lib, .MAP, etc., which all share the same directory as the C/C++ source files.  I don't want to delete the source files, only the built-files.  And yes, I probably should rework the directory structure, to use a separate directory for the built-files [only], but that will take time, and I need a quick solution now.)

How can I merge the above command with "something" else (e.g., like the 'rm -f' command???), to carry this the one step further, to actually delete [only] those filtered-out files from the current directory?  (I'm hopeful for a solution which does not require a temporary file to hold the filtered file names.)

Comment: `find /path/to/some/directory -iname '*.exe' -delete`

Comment: I should note a small error in the problem description:  "ls | grep '.*\.[eE][xX][eE]' " is actually the command that is needed to get ALL ".exe" file-names (I've added a '*' to follow the "match-any-character" '.', in the regex).  (What I had originally would only match single-character file-names, such as "t.exe".)

Comment: `grep '.\.[eE][xX][eE]'` would match anything that `grep '.*\.[eE][xX][eE]'` matches. Use [`grep '.'` in place of `grep '..*'`](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#wc) whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this answer because the accepted answer is suggesting practices which are not-recommended in actual scripts. (Please don't feel bad, I was also on that track once..)

Parsing ls output is a NO-NO! See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for more detailed explanation on why.

In short, `ls` separates the filenames with newline; which can be present in the filename itself. (Plus, ls does not handle other special characters properly. `ls` prints the output in *human* readable form.) In unix/linux, it's perfectly valid to have a newline in the filename.

A unix filename cannot have a NULL character though. Hence below command should work.

```
find /path/to/some/directory -iname '*.exe' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

1. [`find`](http://man.he.net/?section=all&topic=find): is a tool used to, well, find files matching the required pattern/criterion.
2. `-iname`: search using particular names, case insensitive. Note that the argument to `-iname` is wildcard, not regex.
3. `-print0`: Print the file names separated by `NULL` character.
4. [`xargs`](http://man.he.net/?section=all&topic=xargs): Takes the input from stdin & runs the commands supplied (`rm -f` in this case) on them. The input is separaed by white-space by default.
5. `-0` specifies that the input is separated by null character.

Or even better approach,

```
find /path/to/some/directory -iname '*.exe' -delete
```

`-delete` is a built-in feature of find, which deletes the files found with the pattern.

Note that if you want to do some other operation, like move them to particular directory, you'd need to use first option with xargs.

Finally, this command `find /path/to/some/directory -iname '*.exe' -delete` would recursively find the `*.exe` files/directories. You can restrict the search to current directory with `-maxdepth 1` & filetype to simple file (not directory, pipe etc.) using `-type f`. Check the manual link I provided for more details.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you mean?

```
rm -f `ls | grep '.\.[eE][xX][eE]'`
```

but usually your "ls | grep ..." output will have some other fields that you have to strip out such as date etc., so you might just want to output the file name itself.

try something like:

```
rm -f `ls | grep '.\.[eE][xX][eE]' | awk '{print $9}'`
```

where you file name is in the 9th field like:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Administrators None       283 Jul  2  2014 search.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command:

```
ls | grep '.\.[eE][xX][eE]' | xargs rm -f
```

Use of "xargs" would turn standard input ( in this case output of the previous command) as arguments for "rm -f" command.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about xargs.  I did find a simpler way, on my own, although it does not use grep:  rm -f ./*.[eE][xX][eE]